# Why are the bails taken-off from the stumps?

Tags: rules, cricket, wicket

Why are the **bails taken-off** from the stumps at the break time & end of the day of a Test-match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Law 16.2, 16.3](https://www.lords.org/mcc/laws-of-cricket/laws/law-16-start-of-play-cessation-of-play/):

> The bowler’s end umpire shall call Time when the ball is dead on the
>   cessation of play before any interval or interruption and at the
>   conclusion of the match. After the call of Time, the bails shall be
>   removed from both wickets.

So, this is the official way to show that the match has been paused or finished.